# Does Raspberry Pi support NFC?

Tags: networking, nfc

Does the Raspberry pi work with NFC and specifically communicating with an Android phone? Are there any NFC cards that are better / worse than others for working on the pi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the RPi can talk NFC, it should be able to talk to any NFC equipped Android Phone (or NFC equipped device in general). I personally did not play with that combination, but I found a [tutorial](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/index.php/documentation/tutorials/rfid-13-56-mhz-nfc-module-for-raspberry-pi) on this subject. It uses a RPi and a 13.56 Mhz shield for the NFC/RFID communication. The only thing that worries me in the text is that an Arduino suddenly pops up, I guess that is not the idea to also add an Arduino.

I found a [second source of information](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2012/08/03/tutorial-adafruit-nfcrfid-on-raspberry-pi-piday-raspberrypi-raspberry_pi/) from Ada Fruits, they have a ready to use piece of hardware and they also have a library to communicate with the hardware, this might be a fast solution to start using NFC/RFID. In the text I only see that they use of for reading mifare cards, so plain RFID, but making this talk to an Android device is just a matter of a (little) programming.

Comment: The AdaFruit tutorial looks promising!

Comment: Found something else interesting [here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~db434/raspi/nfc/), they use NFC to communicate with a robot they built